# Wrap each element in separate ul list

Tags: jquery, html

I have mutli `<a>` element wrapped into one div and I would like to wrap all the `<a>` tags into a `<ul>` list.

The html look like this :

```
<div id='MyId'>
 <a href='#'><span>1</span></a>
 <a href='#'><span>2</span></a>
 <a href='#'><span>3</span></a>
 <a href='#'><span>4</span></a>
 <a href='#'><span>5</span></a>
</div>
```

And I would like to have

```
<div id='MyId'>
 <ul>
   <li>
     <a href='#'><span>1</span></a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href='#'><span>2</span></a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href='#'><span>3</span></a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href='#'><span>4</span></a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href='#'><span>5</span></a>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I tried with jquery but I'm not able to do it

```
$('#MyId').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
      html  = $this.html(),
      skel  = '<ul><li>'+ html +'</li></ul>';

  $this.closest('div').html('');

  $('#MyId').append(skel);

});
```

Here some [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5zh77tep/3/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **[`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)** and **[`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)** methods

```js
$('#MyId a')
  .wrapAll('<ul>') // wrap all elements by `ul`
  .wrap('<li>'); // wrap each element by `li`

console.log(
  $('#MyId').html()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='MyId'>
  <a href='#'><span>1</span></a>
  <a href='#'><span>2</span></a>
  <a href='#'><span>3</span></a>
  <a href='#'><span>4</span></a>
  <a href='#'><span>5</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `wrap()` and `wrapInner()` link: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```js
$('#MyId > a').wrap('<li></li>');
// Wrap all a tag with <li></li>
$('#MyId').wrapInner('<ul></ul>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='MyId'>
  <a href='#'><span>1</span></a>
  <a href='#'><span>2</span></a>
  <a href='#'><span>3</span></a>
  <a href='#'><span>4</span></a>
  <a href='#'><span>5</span></a>
</div>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5zh77tep/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wrapInner()` to wrap content of `#MyId` div in `ul` and then use `wrap()` to wrap each `a` in `li`

```js
$('#MyId').wrapInner('<ul>')
$('#MyId a').wrap('<li>');
```

```css
li { display:block; list-style:none }
li > a { display:block; margin:.5em 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='MyId'>
  <a href='#'><span>1</span></a>
  <a href='#'><span>2</span></a>
  <a href='#'><span>3</span></a>
  <a href='#'><span>4</span></a>
  <a href='#'><span>5</span></a>
</div>
```